# Why does UITableView setContentOffset not work properly when reloadRows was called before?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

It seems that `tableView.setContentOffset(, animated: )`  does not work properly when `tableView.reloadRows(at: , with: )` was called before.

If `reloadRows` was called `setContentOffset` moves the TableView up and down a few pixels but does not scroll to the right position. Only when calling `setContentOffset` a second time the scrolling performed correctly.

**Is this a know problem, a bug or am I doing something wrong?**

---

#### Code

The problem can be reproduced with a simple `UIViewController` which contains only a `UINavigationBar` with two `UIBarButtonItems` and a `UITableView`.

The BarButtons are used to trigger `reloadRows` and `setContentOffset`. The TableView Contains a simple list of 10 standard `UITableViewCell`s with some text.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    //  Actions
    @IBAction func leftBarButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Scroll up 100px
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y + 100), animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func rightBarButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Reload first row
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .none)
    }


    //  TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defaultCell") ?? UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Item No \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

}
```

- Show the ViewController
- Tap the leftBarButton to trigger `setContentOffset` and scroll the TableView up a bit. This works fine
- Tap the rightBarButton to trigger `reloadRows`. First row will be reloaded (not visible)
- Tap the leftBarButton to trigger `setContentOffset` again. The TableView will only move slightly instead of scrolling correctly
- Tap the leftBarButton to trigger `setContentOffset` again. Now scrolling will work again.

**Any ideas how to prevent this strange behaviour?**

Answer (score 1):

```
    @IBAction func leftBarButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Scroll up 100px
       tableView.beginUpdates()
       tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y + 100), animated: true)
       tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean. There are two button to trigger two different actions (setContentOffset or reloadRows). Thus there are two `IBAction` outlets...

Comment: They have the same signature :) Bot of the hem is **reftBarButtonAction**

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this was obviously only a typo I have now corrected. But since it was not the same method name (left vs. reft) this does not have any influence on the described problem.

Comment: Ok, we have some progress at least :)  How about in that way? You may try without animation also.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace you code for leftBarButtonAction with below. Hope it works. :)

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y + 100), animated: true)
```